# How I assign the value inside a textbox into the scriptlet variable and set the value into session variable

Tags: html, session-variables, jsp-tags, scriptlet

How I assign the value inside a textbox into the scriptlet variable and set the value into session variable....

```
<body>
.
.
.

<input type="text" name="txtValue" id="txtValue">
.
.
.


<%
String valueString="txtValue";

request.getSession().setSession("setValue","valueString");

%>

</body>
```

here "txtValue" is a textbox.I want to get the value stored into the textbox and want to assign the value to scriptlet variable which is valueString.I also want to put the value inside the session attribute.

What will be the right Syntax?????? Please help ...

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to mix the server side and client side code .. since jsp content loads before java-scripts do, it is a tough job .

However you can try using  :

```
<% request.getSession().setSession("setValue","
<script type="text/javascript" >
        document.getElementById("txtValue").value;
    </script> 
<% ");%>
```

Im skeptical but it might work